# Identifying inertial system without already having an inertial system?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, inertial-frames, definition

Learning some basic physics principles via Spivak's Physics for Mathematicians, and he rephrases Newton's first law as

> Newton's First Law: There is at least one coordinate system — an inertial system — in which any object not acted upon by any forces has constant velocity.

In practice, do we have a way to measure forces that doesn't rely on choice of coordinate system?

The only way I can think of to measure forces relies on choosing a coordinate system (an inertial frame).  For instance, I see a lead ball placed atop of a spring compress the spring, and the deceleration here is informing me about the force.  However, I am only able to observe deceleration because I have put myself at the centre of a coordinate system, not the ball.

So my current understanding is that to pick an inertial system we first need to know the forces in the system, but to identify forces in a system we first need to pick an inertial system.  To break this circular dependency, shouldn't there be a way to define forces independent of the inertial system chosen?

Answer (score 2):

> In practice, do we have a way to measure forces that doesn't rely on choice of coordinate system?

Yes, we use accelerometers (more properly inertial measurement units which measure acceleration on three axes and rotation about three axes).

Regardless of your coordinate system, if your accelerometer reads 0 then the object is moving inertially. An inertial frame is then a system of coordinates where all such objects have straight worldlines.

Note, this implies that inertial frames are free falling frames, which is different from how Newton originally consider things, but in modern physics it has been found to be better.

Comment: An object at rest on a table still squishes the table.

Comment: @candied_orange yes, obviously

Comment: Coming back to thinking about this again now - doesn't using an accelerometer require the choice of an inertial frame?  To get a reading from the accelerometer, we essentially read how much a tiny spring is compressed/elongated, but this accelerometer needs a reference point in time when it knows it's not being accelerated to set a reference point to itself being a rest, that is, reading 0.

Comment: @Ryder Bergerud no, using an accelerometer does not require choosing an inertial frame. An accelerometer measures proper acceleration. Proper acceleration is an invariant, meaning that it is the same in all reference frames, inertial or non-inertial and all spacetimes, curved or flat. This is in contrast to coordinate acceleration which does require the specification of a reference frame